# Connecting to local runtime google colab with GPU needs tensorflow-gpu?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, google-colaboratory

My PC has no GPU installed and to speed up execution I want to use GPU suggested by google colab by connecting to a local runtime (because the dataset I'm using is too large to be uploaded on google drive). I have normal tensorflow installed on my pc and when I try to run my code on google colab with GPU there's no change in speed. To be able to use google colab GPU do I need to install tensorflow-gpu on my pc? The version of tensorflow-gpu must be the same as tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to enable `GPUs` for the notebook in Google Colab:

Navigate to `Edit` and select `Notebook Settings`

Select `GPU` from the `Hardware Accelerator` drop-down

After that You can confirm that we connected to the GPU with tensorflow by running below code:

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
import tensorflow as tf
device_name = tf.test.gpu_device_name()
if device_name != '/device:GPU:0':
  raise SystemError('GPU device not found')
print('Found GPU at: {}'.format(device_name))
```

Output:

```
TensorFlow 2.x selected.
Found GPU at: /device:GPU:0
```

Please refer this [link](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html) suggested by `Google Colab` to connect with `local runtime`,

Answer (score 0):

If you use local runtime in *Google Colab*, you rely on your local hardware so in your case, without GPU as you mentioned.
In any case Colab [local runtime](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html) makes use of *Jupyter* runtime or *docker* runtime on your local machine so there's nothing more to install as the configuration is provided by these runtimes.